# Using a helper function in a .find jquery line in Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I have a helper function that I have set up to convert a time stamp into a readable date in Laravel 4.  The function is called "getDate" in the file StringEdit.php (in the folder "helpers").  I know this function works.

I am trying to use this function in a jquery call that takes data from a database and loads it to a div id (loading more data with each click).  Here is the code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

<?php $number_of_posts = 2; ?>;
<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = isset($_SESSION['posts_start']) ? $_SESSION['posts_start'] : $number_of_posts; ?>;
//<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = $_SESSION['posts_start'] ? $_SESSION['posts_start'] : $number_of_posts; ?>;
//<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = 2 ?>;

//var start = <?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start']; ?>;

var start = {{ Session::get('posts_start', 2) }};
var initialPosts = <?php echo Fanartist::friend_activity_json(0, $_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>;
//var initialPosts = <?php echo Fanartist::friend_activity_json(0, 2); ?>;
var desiredPosts = <?php echo $number_of_posts; ?>;


var template = '<tr>'
               +'<td>'
               +'<div class="friend_image">'
               +'<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/fbid/picture" alt="" height="65" width="65" class="img-rounded">'
               +'</div>'
               +'</td>'
               +'<td>'
               +'<div class="friend_activity">'
               +'<span class="activity_text"><span class="first_name"></span> <span class="last_name"></span> indicated that <span class="gender"></span> wants <a href="/artists/artist_id"><span class="stage_name"></span></a> to come to <span class="city"></span></span>'
               +'<br><span class="activity_subtext"><span class="created_at"></span></span>'
               +'</div>'
               +'</td>'
               +'</tr>';

var activity = $('#activity'),
    // Element to load the posts
    content = activity.find('.content'),
    // the more button
    more = activity.find('.more'),
    // the post counter
    counter = activity.find('.badge');

// Create alerts elements (Display Success or Failure)
    var alerts = {
        requestEmpty : $('<div class="alert alert-info">No more data</div>'),
        requestFailure : $('<div class="alert alert-error">Could not get the data. Try again!</div>')
    }
    var progressElement = $('<div class="progress" style="margin-bottom:0"><div class="bar"></div></div>');
    var progressBar = progressElement.find('.bar');

    var postHandler = function(posts){

        // Set the progress bar to 100%
        progressBar.css('width', '100%');
        // Delay the normal more button to come back for a better effect
        window.setTimeout(function(){more.html('More <span class="caret"></span>')}, 500);

        // insert childrens at the end of the content element


        for (post in posts){
            // Clone the element
            var $post = $(template).clone();
            $post.attr('id', 'post-' + posts[post].ID);

            var $img = $post.find('div.friend_image').find('img');
            $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace('fbid', posts[post].fbid));
            $img.attr('alt', posts[post].first_name);

            var $spantext = $post.find('div.friend_activity').find('span.activity_text');
            $spantext.html($spantext.html().replace('artist_id', posts[post].artist_id));

            //$post.find('.fbid').html(posts[post].fbid);
            $post.find('.first_name').html(posts[post].first_name);
            $post.find('.last_name').html(posts[post].last_name);
            $post.find('.city').html(posts[post].city);
            $post.find('.gender').html(posts[post].gender == 'male' ? 'he' : 'she');
            //$post.find('.artist_id').html(posts[post].artist_id);
            $post.find('.stage_name').html(posts[post].stage_name);
            $post.find('.created_at').html(posts[post].created_at);
            content.append($post);

        }


        content.animate({
            scrollTop: $('#post-' + posts[0].ID).offset().top + (content.scrollTop()- content.offset().top)
        }, 200);

    }

    // place the initial posts in the page
    postHandler(initialPosts);

    // add the click event to the more button
    more.click(function(){  
        // Set the progress bar to 0%
        progressBar.css('width', '0%');
        // remove the more button innerHTML and insert the progress bar
        more.empty().append(progressElement);
        // AJAX REQUEST
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://crowdtest.dev:8888/fans/setup_widget", 
            type: 'GET',
            // We do not want IE to cache the result
            cache: false,
            data: {  
                'start': start,  
                'desiredPosts': desiredPosts  
            }
        }).success(function (data, text) {
            // parse the response (typeof data == String)
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data.length > 0){
                // Update the total number of items
                start += data.length;
                // Update the counter
                counter.html(start);
                // load items on the page
                postHandler(data);
            }else{
                $alert = alerts.requestEmpty;
                // insert the empty message
                activity.prepend($alert);
                // Set the progress bar to 100%
                progressBar.css('width', '100%');
                // Remove the more button
                window.setTimeout(function(){more.remove()}, 500);
                // remove the empty message after 4 seconds
                window.setTimeout(function(){$alert.remove()}, 4000);
            }
        }).error(function (request, status, error) {
            $alert = alerts.requestFailure;
            // insert the failure message
            activity.prepend($alert);
            // Set the progress bar to 100%
            progressBar.css('width', '100%');
            // Delay the normal more button to come back for a better effect
            window.setTimeout(function(){more.html('More <span class="caret"></span>')}, 500);
        });

    });

console.log(desiredPosts);
console.log(start);
console.log(initialPosts);

});
</script>
```

which is called in the html using the div id "activity":

```
<div id="activity">
    <table class="table table-striped">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                   <th><div class="friend_image"></div></th>
                   <th><div class="friend_activity"></div></th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody class="content">

               </tbody>
    </table>
<button class="more btn btn-block">
        More <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

Everything is output correctly, except for the created_at portion.  I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

referencing the line:

```
$post.find('.created_at').html(posts[post].StringEdit::getDate(created_at));
```

Do you know how I would call this function to edit the created_at entity from the database within jquery?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing here? `$post.find('.created_at').html(posts[post].StringEdit::getDate(created_at));` How are you trying to call a PHP class and function from within javascript?

Comment: Well I know it's wrong, but I don't know how to do it...I want to alter the value that is being returned in the jquery with that PHP class and function.

Comment: is the first code snippet on a .js file or on the blade.php file? I would be able to advice on this accordingly.

Comment: is the posts variable bound through jquery ajax?

Comment: it's in the blade file itself.  And the post variable is bound through ajax.

Comment: can you post the complete jquery code and the rendered code

Comment: yes, I just posted the full jquery code.  My question remains, how do I use the php function getDate to alter the output for the created_at field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your reply, concerning the variables passed to blade template, you wrote that the javascript code you present - "it's in the blade file itself. And the post variable is bound through ajax." 

I guess the solution is quite simple - you can accomplish your needs wity blade and php only, without JS (which is redundant in you case)

**in your laravel controller** 
1) pass the $posts variable to the view (than return it, display or whatever your templating implementation is)

```
View::make('posts', $posts);
```

**in your blade template**
1) feed posts variable to the template as you do already
2) structure the "template" variable u have in javascript as a blade template php code
3) use blade to fill the variables with data (instead of parsing the template code with JS like you do now)

some example below (just a snippet):

```
// app/views/posts.blade.php

{{-- this is a blade comment --}}

<div id="activity">
<table class="table table-striped">
           <thead>
               <tr>
               <th><div class="friend_image"></div></th>
               <th><div class="friend_activity"></div></th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody class="content">

{{-- in the below foreach loop you put the html you currently have in javascript template variable var template; --}}

@foreach ($posts as $post)


{{-- inside the foreach loop you have access to all your $posts, so while iterating you can do:  --}}


{{-- 1) access $post fields --}}
{{ $post->id }} 
{{ $post->fbid }} 
{{ $post->whatever }} 

{{-- 2) access $post fields and apply function on them --}}
{{ StringEdit::getDate($post->whatever) }} 

@endforeach 

    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="more btn btn-block">
    More <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

If you do as suggested, you wont have to bug with Php to Javascript issues and it does seem a cleaner and more simple solution to your problem. And ofcourse you will have what you asked for - you will be able to use the string helper function in the template :)

**EDIT:** 
I updated the above post to include info from discussion in the comments

**EDIT 2:**
Answering your follow up request from the comments:

**Using a custom Eloquent model accessor**

Suppose you have a field (datacolumn) in your model (which ofcourse is ment to represent a table in the database), the field's name is MyFancyField. Now, for your system you need to have a possibility, to fetch this field's content preprocessed - you need it to be uppercase. So you create a custom accessor like below and refer to it (use it) like it is another field of your model.

**The Model: /app/models/Book.php**

```
class Book extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'books';

    public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();
    foreach ($this->getMutatedAttributes() as $key)
    {
        if ( ! array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            $array[$key] = $this->{$key};   
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

public function getUpperMyFancyField()
{
    return strtoupper($this->myFancyField);    
}

}
```

**The controller: /app/controllers/**

```
public function index(Book $book)
{
$this->book = $book;  

echo "The original field fetched by a default accessor: "  . $this->book->myFancyField;
echo "The uppercased field fetched by another custom accessor: "  . $this->book->upperMyFancyField;

}
```

Just for the record, the toArray() is overloaded on purpose because Laravel 4 by default does not include the "custom accessor fields" into the returned object as array. So if you didnt have that, and wanted $this->book->toArray() it wouldnt include upperMyFancyField in there.

Comment: is there any way to do this with the javascript intact?  The only issue is I want to maintain the "load-more" functionality, where it only shows more data when a button is clicked.

Comment: Also when I do this, I am getting the error "undefined variable posts";  could you show how I declare posts in the javascript that allows me to use it in the foreach loop?

Comment: The foreach loop is a php-ish loop not javascript. The whole idea behind my proposal is doing the processing server side with PHP rather than in Javascript. As per your question, you have to pass the $posts variable from the controller to the template to use it ( View::make('posts', $posts); )

Comment: Ok, the issue is I want this to have "load-more" functionality, and I have a function in my model that takes two variables: friend_activity_json($start, $number_of_posts).  When I try to include this in the page with the controller when I make the view, it says I am supplying an invalid argument.

Comment: Your accessor solution is more in line with what I want to do.  Can you expound on that?  I would like to keep the javascript as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use an [Accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) on the eloquent model from the database, so you dont even need the getDate() function at all?

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function getCreatedAt($value)
    {
        // created_at will now be formatted as "d-m-Y"
        return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value));
    }

}
```

Just change the date() function format to whatever you need (i.e. same as your getDate() function format)

Comment: The issue is I don't want this field to be altered in this way all the time, I just want it altered in this specific instance.

Comment: is there any way to have this Accessor only affect certain queries?

Comment: You can create a dummy accessor getFormattedCreatedAt($value) and depending on the occasion, call either the "normal" accessor for the real field getCreatedAt or the other accessor getFormattedCreatedAt to access the preprocessed 'dummy' data .

Comment: Could you add a code example of this to your answer?  I'm having trouble implementing this.